Is there a delayed effect from reopening a question on subsequent close votes coming soon after?
This happened recently:

A question was closed as a duplicate. I wasn't involved in this closing.
It was reopened by two users with close-vote privileges but no special privileges, and one with a dupehammer, who also wasn't involved in (1).
I disagreed and voted to close it again 2-3 minutes after (2).

A few minutes later, when I load the question again, I noticed that that the question no longer showed "close (1)" like it should have. The close vote dialog now shows the infamous "You cannot vote again after retracting your vote". Now I think that this is likely because the post was closed and reopened again. I didn't retract my vote - the dialog doesn't say I have, and it is supposed to do so if I had. I suppose it's possible that the user with the dupehammer could have closed and reopened it. However, the post's revision history and timeline do not show any closures or reopens after (2). So what happened to my close vote? Is there a known delay between reopening and whatever disables ability of users who have already voted to close once from voting again?

I don't know what happened or if this is related, but the dupe target has been closed as a dupe of the source question, making your dupe vote attempting a circular dupe now. I guess it's automatically retracted by the system due to that.

Can't you just check the revisions, and see what happened?

Also, what you linked to means that it should, but it does not work in the expected way, i.e. the dialog give wrong message.

@ShadowWizard "However, the post's revision history and timeline do not show any closures or reopens after (2)" and for the dialog giving the wrong message, the point of that post is that if I had actually retracted, then the dialog does show that I had done so (the last line in the dialog shown in the second screenshot).

But yes, @MetaAndrewT. is right, the other question was closed as a duplicate of this one. That's definitely it.

The question you believe is a duplicate of the question that you were trying to close was actually closed as a duplicate of the question you were trying to close. If the question had been closed, they would have each been listed as dupes of each other.
To make even more obvious why this is a problem, I think unregistered users would likely get a too many redirects error (if the posts had no answers) as I’m pretty sure that they are redirected to the duplicate target.
Because of this, the system likely auto-retracted your close vote.
